# Lua чтение чисел из файла

Tags: lua

В файле содержатся целые числа в десятичном виде.

```
function tobin(num)
local tmp = {}
repeat
tmp[#tmp+1]=num%2
num = math.floor(num/2)
until num==0
return table.concat(tmp):reverse()
end
```

вот функция для перевода числа в двоичный вид, а как мне считать из файла все числа, и приводить их в качестве аргумента функции?

Comment: > каждые восемь двоичных символов превращались в букву латинского алфавита - -
Боюсь шифрование будет необратимым, букв то всего 52 с учётом регистра.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> как мне считать с файла все числа, и приводить их в качестве аргумента функции?

например, так:

```
io.input("имя.файла")
while true do
  local val = io.read("*number")
  if val == nil then break end
  print(val) -- вызывайте свою функцию вместо print
end
io.close()
```

---

если в файле хранится, например:

```
12345 67890
332211
```

то результатом выполнения будет:

```
12345
67890
332211
```

---

подробнее — в [документации](https://www.lua.org/pil/21.1.html).