# Lua чтение разнородных данных из файла

Tags: lua

> В файле содержатся целые числа в десятичном виде. Преобразовать каждое
>   число в двоичную форму. Выполнить шифрование данных таким образом,
>   чтобы каждые восемь двоичных символов превращались в букву латинского
>   алфавита. Таблица соответствия кодов буквам содержится во втором
>   файле. Предусмотреть функцию для выполнения дешифрования.

Если в файле должна храниться таблица соответствия чисел буквам, к примеру

```
11001100 A
11010111 B
11110101 C
```

как мне их занести в таблицу в программе

```
{
['10010011']='A',
['10110000']='B',
...
}
```

что бы потом сравнивать их с уже существующими числами, и в последствии произвести замену числа на букву?

```
    function tobin(num)
        local tmp = {}
        repeat
            tmp[#tmp+1]=num%2
            num = math.floor(num/2)
        until num==0
        return table.concat(tmp):reverse()
    end

    local function main()
     io.input("number.txt")

    while true do
      local val = io.read("*number")
      if val == nil then break end
      local a = {}
      a = tobin(val) 
      print(tostring(a))
     end   
   ......


    end
    main()
```

Comment: ---------------

Comment: (инструкция по объединению учётных записей)[http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts]. это по поводу http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/563553/178576

Comment: спасибо сделаю.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> как мне их занести в таблицу в программе

например, так:

```
local a = {} -- объявление должно быть за пределами цикла
io.input("имя.файла") -- открываем файл на чтение
while true do
  local line = io.read("*line") -- читаем целую строку
  if line == nil then break end -- если ничего не прочиталось -
                                -- конец цикла
  x,y = string.match(line,"([01]+) (%a)") -- двоичные цифры
                                -- помещаем в x, букву - в y
  a[x]=y -- добавляем эту пару в ассоциативный массив
end

-- отладочный вывод 
for k,v in pairs(a) do
  print("["..k.."]="..v)
end

--[[
при входных данных:
11001100 A
11010111 B
11110101 C

напечатает:
[11001100]=A
[11010111]=B
[11110101]=C
--]]
```

---

### обновление

так как таблицы в *lua* [реализованы в виде ассоциативных массивов](https://www.lua.org/pil/2.5.html) «ключ/значение», то для хранения в строке таблицы **двух** произвольных значений можно использовать *вложенную* таблицу:

```
local a = {} -- объявление должно быть за пределами цикла
local n = 1  -- инициализируем счётчик элементов таблицы
io.input("имя.файла") -- открываем файл на чтение
while true do
  local line = io.read("*line") -- читаем целую строку
  if line == nil then break end -- если ничего не прочиталось -
                                -- конец цикла
  x,y = string.match(line,"([01]+) (%a)") -- двоичные цифры
                                -- помещаем в x, букву - в y
  a[n]={ x,y } -- добавляем эту пару в таблицу в виде
               -- вложенной таблицы
  n=n+1        -- увеличиваем счётчик
end

-- отладочный вывод 
for k,v in pairs(a) do
  print(v[1].."="..v[2]) -- обращаемся к элементам вложенной
                         -- таблицы по их номерам
end

--[[
при входных данных:
11001100 A
11010111 B
11110101 C
11001100 D
11111110 E
11001001 F

напечатает:
11001100=A
11010111=B
11110101=C
11001100=D
11111110=E
11001001=F
--]]
```

Comment: спасибо, только вот файл
11001100 A
11010111 B
11110101 C
11001100 D
11111110 E
11001001 F
а вывод
[11001100]=D
[11001001]=F
[11010111]=B
[11110101]=C
[11111110]=E

Comment: получается выводит не в той последовательности и еще пропускает первую строку

Comment: 1. по поводу «непоследовательности» — видимо, такова реализация ассоциативного массива в *lua*. см. [статью про реализации](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2#.D0.A0.D0.B5.D0.B0.D0.BB.D0.B8.D0.B7.D0.B0.D1.86.D0.B8.D0.B8_.D0.B0.D1.81.D1.81.D0.BE.D1.86.D0.B8.D0.B0.D1.82.D0.B8.D0.B2.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.B3.D0.BE_.D0.BC.D0.B0.D1.81.D1.81.D0.B8.D0.B2.D0.B0). 2. по поводу «пропускает» — для букв `A` и `D` у вас одинаковый ключ: `11001100`. соответственно, сохраняется последнее значение: `D`.

Comment: возможно, вам имеет смысл в качестве ключа использовать букву, а не число. ну, раз числа могут повторяться для разных букв.

Comment: @P.L, дополнил ответ.

Comment: не подскажите дальше, как их теперь сравнить с теми двоичными числами, и заменить их на букву если, они равны?

Comment: если у вас возник новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки в правом верхнем углу страницы. подсказка: опишите в вопросе подробнее, как именно вы сравниваете два значения и какие ошибки при этом получаете.