# Lua сравнение,чисел и ключей таблиц

Tags: lua

> В файле содержатся целые числа в десятичном виде. Преобразовать каждое
>   число в двоичную форму. Выполнить шифрование данных таким образом,
>   чтобы каждые восемь двоичных символов превращались в букву латинского
>   алфавита. Таблица соответствия кодов буквам содержится во втором
>   файле. Предусмотреть функцию для выполнения дешифрования.

```
function tobin(num)
        local tmp = {}
        repeat
            tmp[#tmp+1]=num%2
            num = math.floor(num/2)
        until num==0 
        return table.concat(tmp):reverse()
    end

    local function main()
     io.input("number.txt")
     local m = {}
      for i = 1, 6 do
        local val = io.read("*number")
          if val == nil then break end
            m[i] = tobin(val)
        print(m[i])end


     local a = {} 
     --local n = 1 
    io.input("shfr.txt") 
    while true do
      local line = io.read("*line") 
      if line == nil then break end 
      x,y = string.match(line,"([01]+) (%a)") 

      a[x] = y 
    end

    for k,v in pairs(a) do
      print("["..k.."]="..v)
    end

      for i = 1, 6 do
     if a[m[i]]  then m[i] = y end
     print(m[i])
      end


    io.close()
    end
    main()
```

здесь пытался сравнивать двоичные числа, с ключом и заменять на букву которая находиться в значении ключа. но выдает только F F F F F

```
 for i = 1, 6 do
         if a[m[i]]  then m[i] = y end
         print(m[i])
          end
```

так выглядит таблица

```
[11001001]=F
[11001100]=D
[11001110]=A
[11110101]=C
[11111110]=E
[11010111]=B


 а это m[i]
11001110
11010111
11110101
11001100
11111110
11001001
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if a[m[i]]  then m[i] = y end`

### А чему равна глобальная переменная `y`?

там  последнее значение из цикла чтения shfr.txt. Замени на `a[m[i]]`

Comment: x,y = string.match(line,"([01]+) (%a)") 
      a[x] = y Она не равна значению ключа разве?

Answer (score -1):

с предложенной в этом вопросе таблицей, отформатированной в том же виде, как в [вашем предыдущем вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/563888/178576), и с входными данными, озвученными в этом вопросе, вот такой простенький код:

```
local a={}

for line in io.lines("таблица") do
  local x,y=string.match(line,"([01]+) (%a)")
  a[x]=y
end

for line in io.lines("входные.данные") do
  print(a[line])
end
```

выведет то, что вы, вероятно, ожидаете:

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

---

бесплатная рекомендация: если вам надо написать программу на каком-нибудь языке программирования, и вы не хотите освоить даже самые азы этого языка, то быстрее и проще не просить написать вам программу по кусочкам ([раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/563553/178576) и [два](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/563888/178576)), а потом не очень осмысленно пытаться сложить эти кусочки воедино, а сразу обратиться на какую-нибудь биржу фриланса. удачи!